# Adjust text size as per the device specifications

Tags: android, textview, text-size

I know this question has been answered many times, and i have tried almost all solution available here, but none of them seems to be working in my case.

I want to set the text size of each textview component in the manner that it automatically gets adjusted on different device sizes. Let's say i have a heading, body and source text fields and the heading size would be greater than that of body and source text sizes.
Currently if i am trying some solutions by setting the text sizes as per the device density, but on some device it's perfect and on some device it's coming very small.

I have tried these solutions:
[Text size and different android screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877946/text-size-and-different-android-screen-sizes)

[Android set TextView text size to look the same on all screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962554/android-set-textview-text-size-to-look-the-same-on-all-screen-sizes)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If no other solution works for you consider using a library like this one: https://github.com/intuit/ssp

Comment: This worked like a charm. :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the best library. I used in many of my projects

[https://github.com/intuit/ssp](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)   <---   for textviews size (sp)

https://github.com/intuit/sdp   <---   for views size (dp)

You have just put this line in your app level gradle

```
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
```

Comment: Thanks @Sohel S9 It seems to be working, before i accept the answer i want to test it on 2 more devices, once i am done testing with them, will accept the answer :)

Comment: You should also check in 7 and 10 inch tablet.